# JavaFX Glass shatter / crack and break

Tags: java, animation, javafx, effects

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can go about creating an Effect for a JavaFX node that can simulate glass shattering and then (potentially) breaking? if the breaking is more difficult, I can skip that part. Basically I want to layer this pane over an image and then make it look like its a picture frame that then shatters. If it can then break into pieces (after some configurable delay).. that would be great as well!

I've looked everywhere but can't seem to find info on simulating the glass shatter effect in JavaFX.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple solution I'd go with a [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Path.html) that randomly extends and change the style of the path during time.

More sophisticated code could use a [Canvas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html) and paint the shattering on it. Daniel Shiffman with his [Nature of Code](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-8-fractals/) book may be a base for you with the creation of the shatter effect.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers... I'll start researching those. Seems this question got put on hold for being too broad, which it probably is.